# Special Characters and Encoding

Tags: python, mysql, django, encoding, character-encoding

Although there are hundreds of questions of this kind, there isn't an appropriate answer helping me to understand and solve my problem.

I wanted to switch from a SQLite database to a MySQL database in my django installation. Everything works fine, and I can still add special characters via the admin interface, however, it raises an encoding error when using the `save()` method on user generated input.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any hints?

**edit**

Database Character Set:

```
mysql> show variables like "character_set_database";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| character_set_database | utf8  |
+------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "collation_database";
+--------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name      | Value           |
+--------------------+-----------------+
| collation_database | utf8_general_ci |
+--------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 48, in <module>
    add_categories_to_db()
  File "myscript.py", line 38, in add_categories_to_db
    cat.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 898, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 264, in literal
    return self.escape(o, self.encoders)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 197, in string_literal
    return db.string_literal(obj)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Your encoding can't handle the special character you gave it. Either use a different encoding or don't use the special character.

Another option would be to replace all instances of this special character with another special character (only choose one that never occurs in your data) within the range of 0-128, and then replace it again when loading.

Comment: The error is caused by some unicode value being implicitly being encoded to ASCII. Can you show us the *full* traceback? What characterset did you configure your database with?

Comment: There is default encoding for a database, encoding for a table, and encoding for a connection.

Comment: The encoding of which system? My django app can handle it since it worked before with sqlite, and the mysql db can handle it since it can take the input from the admin interface.